# How do I save images to folder after face recognized and cropped?

Tags: python-3.x, face-detection

I am working on face detecting and then cropping face from image, i can crop the face but I can't save them to another folder. My code is below

import cv2
    import os
    import glob

```
def facecrop(image):
    facedata = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" 
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(facedata)

    img = cv2.imread(image)

    minisize = (img.shape[1],img.shape[0])
    miniframe = cv2.resize(img, minisize)

    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(miniframe)

    for f in faces:
        x, y, w, h = [ v for v in f ]
        #cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,0))

        sub_face = img[y:y+h + 500, x:x+w + 500]
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(image)
        save = "./salman/crop/"
        #print(fname)
        #cv2.imwrite(f'{save}"cropped_"{image}{sub_face}')
        cv2.imwrite(fname + "_cropped_"+ext, sub_face)
        #cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(p),(fname + "_cropped_" + ext, sub_face))
    return

for image in glob.glob('./salman/*.jpg'):
        facecrop(image)
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? Any error? Also, what is type of variable `sub_face`?

Comment: its not saving into another folder

Comment: Can you trying it to the same folder and tell me if that happens successfully, just to make sure there is no other problem besides saving it in another folder?

Comment: yes its saving successfully in same folder, but not in another folder named "crop". I tried in some ways as u can see in commented lines.

Comment: Is it because you are using `_cropped_` instead of `crop` in cv2.imwrite()?

Comment: no..its jst a string for name of image like ' image_cropped.jpg'.

Comment: Could you tell what your variable `image` contains? Any specific sample value you can tell?

Comment: it contains images only.

Comment: An image or image path?

Comment: image path only..in last 2 lines i am adding folder to execute.

Comment: Yes, thanks, can you just provide me one such image path from your data? Just wanted to do a test? Just provide one of the values of image?

Comment: u can add any image folder which consists human faces.